# Limit of an integral with a periodic function

Tags: integration, limits, periodic-functions

Let $f , g$ be continuous functions: $f:[0 , 2\pi]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Assume $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}:g(x+2\pi)=g(x)$ and $$\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}  \! {g(x)} \, \mathrm{d}x=0.$$ Show that $$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}  \! {f(x) g(nx)} \, \mathrm{d}x=0.$$

---

I've started evaluating the difference upwards but it seems like no use: $$\left| \int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}  \! {f(x) g(nx)} \, \mathrm{d}x-0 \right|=\left| \int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}  \! {f(x) g(nx)} \, \mathrm{d}x \right|\leq\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}  \! {\left|f(x) g(nx)\right|} \, \mathrm{d}x=\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}  \! {\left|f(x)\right| \left|g(nx)\right|} \, \mathrm{d}x$$ $$=\left|f(\xi)\right| \int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}  \! { \left|g(nx)\right|} \, \mathrm{d}x$$ for some $\xi \in ]0 , 2\pi[$. What's next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $g$ is $2 \pi$ periodic with zero mean, it follows that $t \mapsto g(nt)$ is $\frac{2 \pi}{n}$ periodic with zero mean. Consequently, if $I \subset [0,2 \pi]$ is any interval of length $\frac{2 \pi}{n}$, then $\int_0^{2 \pi} 1_I(t) g(nt) dt  = 0$.

Let $f_n(t) = f(\frac{2 \pi}{n}\lfloor \frac{nt}{2 \pi} \rfloor)$, and note that $f_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(\frac{k}{n}2 \pi)1_{[\frac{k}{n}2 \pi, \frac{k+1}{n}2 \pi)}$ on $[0,2 \pi)$. It follows from the previous paragraph that $\int_0^{2 \pi} f_n(t) g(nt) dt  = 0$.

Since $f$ is continuous, it is uniformly continuous on $[0,2 \pi]$. Let $\epsilon>0$ and let $\delta>0$ be such that if $|x-y| < \delta$, then $|f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon$. Choose $N$ such that $\frac{2 \pi}{N} < \delta$, and let $n \ge N$. Note that $|f(t)-f_n(t)| < \epsilon$ for all $t$.

Then we have the estimate
\begin{eqnarray}
| \int_0^{2 \pi} f(t) g(nt) dt| &\le &| \int_0^{2 \pi} (f(t)-f_n(t)) g(nt) dt|+ | \int_0^{2 \pi} f_n(t) g(nt) dt| \\
&\le& \int_0^{2 \pi} |f(t)-f_n(t)| |g(nt)| dt + 0\\
&\le& \epsilon \int_0^{2 \pi}  |g(nt)| dt \\
&=& \epsilon \int_0^{2 \pi}  |g(t)| dt
\end{eqnarray}
Hence we have the desired result.

Comment: Sorry for double posting... -- The idea of the proof is now clear to me. However, I find formalizing it a bit difficult. Is it even possible to get the inequalities (2pi/N<delta and n>N) to show in the main evaluation? In addition, I'm not familiar with the usage of \lfloor and \rfloor. What does they mean?

Comment: $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the largest integer $n$ such that $n \le x$. Note that $f_n$ is a 'staircase' approximation to $f$. The choice of $\delta$ is such that $f$ and $f_n$ are no further than $\epsilon$ apart at any time point. This appears implicitly above when I replace $|f(t)-f_n(t)|$ by $\epsilon$. I'm not sure what you mean by 'get the inequalities... to show in the main evaluation'?

Comment: The idea above is that if $f$ is uniformly continuous, then it can be uniformly approximated by a function that is constant on intervals of the form $[k\alpha, (k+1) \alpha)$.

Comment: What I mean by getting the inequalities to show in the main evaluation is that in a basic proof of $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2n+1}{3n+2}=\frac{2}{3}$ you write: let $k>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$, assume $n>k$, now $\left|\frac{2n+1}{3n+2}-\frac{2}{3}\right|=\left|\frac{-1}{3(3n+2)}\right| = \frac{1}{3(3n+2)} \leq \frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{k} < \frac{1}{\frac{1}{\epsilon}}=\epsilon$. You can see the assumption $n>k$ in the evaluate.

Comment: Hmm, this works when there is a nice formulaic way of relating the $\delta$ to the chosen $\epsilon$. All we have above is uniform continuity, which implies that there is a relationship, but doesn't specify the form. So the best we can do is to note that there is a $\delta>0$ such that something is less than $\epsilon$, etc. Do you see what I am trying to get at?

Comment: For example, if we knew that $f$ was Lipschitz continuous, then we could choose $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{L}$ above, and this would appear in subsequent formulae.

Comment: I see... But it still bothers me that I can't clearly see why I'd choose '$N$ such that $\frac{2 \pi}{N} < \delta$'? It seems like this is not used in the estimate at all - or am I missing something?

Comment: You are missing something (the problem is that spelling out all the details takes time). If you look at $f(t)$, $f_n(t)$, then they agree whenever $t =t_k = k \frac{2 \pi}{N}$ (for suitable $k$, of course). So, we want $t$ to always be within $\frac{2 \pi}{N}$ of some $t_k$. Hence the choice of $\delta$.

Comment: It might be easier to see if you split the integral up into little bits as in $\int_0^{2 \pi} = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \int_{k \frac{2 \pi}{N}}^{(k+1) \frac{2 \pi}{N}}$.

Answer (score 0):

An idea: substitution:

$$u:=nx\Longrightarrow dx=\frac{du}{n}\Longrightarrow \int\limits_0^{2\pi} g(nx)dx=\frac{1}{n}\int\limits_0^{2\pi n} g(u)\,du=0$$

since

$$\int\limits_0^{2n\pi}g(u)\,du=\sum_{k=1}^n\;\int\limits_{2(k-1)\pi}^{2k\pi}g(u)\,du$$

but, for any $\,1\le k\le n\,$:

$$\int\limits_{2(k-1)\pi}^{2k\pi}g(u)\,du=\int\limits_{2(k-1)\pi}^{2k\pi}g(u+2k\pi)\,du=\int\limits_0^{2\pi}g(t)\,dt=0$$

where the second equality follows from the substitution

$$t:=u-2(k-1)\pi\,\;,\;\;dt=du$$